# Delay in UIAutomation not executing, script hangs

Tags: ios, delay, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have the script below where I press a button and want to wait a second to see if the facebook login occurs via an external webview. The problem I am having is the delay() is either seems to hang, or not get called. I never get to "Here":

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
var testFBLogin = true;

var loginView = window.scrollViews()[0];

if (testFBLogin) {
    UIALogger.logMessage("Logging in via Facebook");
    loginView.buttons()["Login Using Facebook"].tap();
    target.delay(1);
    UIALogger.logMessage("Here");
} else {
    UIALogger.logMessage("Logging in via Email");

}
```